# NodeJS - localAddress not shown at server

Tags: c#, javascript, node.js, sockets, tcp

I have the following code connecting to socket server:

```
var client = net.createConnection({ host: "localhost", port: 10101, localAdress: "172.28.28.10" }, function () {

});
```

I have multiple network interfaces defined on my machine, and I want to be able to differentiate from which interface the connection was made (the `localAddress` parameter).

The problem is that the socket server (running on the same machine) interprets every connection attempt as if it is coming from address `127.0.0.1`.

I tried to implement the C# version of socket client using TcpClient, and socket server's `RemoteAddress` property is correctly set to address `172.28.28.10`

Socket server is implemented using C#, but I also tested the above client code on a server written in Node. There was no difference. On Node server the `remoteAddress` was also `172.0.0.1`

I even tried to connect my C# socket client to Node socket server, and Node properly displayed `remoteAddres`, so I think that problem is in the client code.

Does anybody know what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: My guess, is that 127.0.0.1 (localhost) is not routed through 172.28.28.10 IP in any way, even if you ask it through localAddress. Can you change host parameter to be `172.28.28.10` as well? It does not have to be `172.28.28.10`, but any address accessible from "outside" of your computer.

Comment: @alandarev Thank you for your reply. If I change `host` parameter to `172.28.28.8` (another interface defined on my machine), `RemoteEndpoint` on the server is `172.28.28.8`. It seems that `localAddress` parameter is being ignored. Can't figure out why.

Comment: Mystery... Not an answer, but you could try digging the actual net module source code: https://github.com/joyent/node/blob/master/lib/net.js and see how the parameter is being used

Comment: @alandarev I feel so stupid: I misspelled `localAddress` :). I guess it's time to take a break :) Thanks once again!

Comment: I know that feeling...